# Atomic uploads to S3

Tags: amazon-s3

Is there a way to configure an Amazon S3 bucket, or the AWS SDK on iOS, so that all uploads to a bucket are atomic?

That is, I want to configure the bucket or the SDK so that if an upload does not complete successfully, it does not leave the partially uploaded file or any other new object in the bucket.

Comment: As long as you are not using multipart upload,  when you use put_object(), a partial upload (e.g. termination on purpose) will not create a file.  You can try this by uploading 3GB file and terminate the program halfway to confirm this.

Answer (score 4):

Like it was said on the comments, if you're not using multipart uploads, you should get that out of the box.

If you are using multipart uploads, there are two things to consider:

1. An abandoned multipart upload consumes storage space in a holding area, but does not leave an incomplete object in the bucket itself. ListObjects, GET, etc., cannot see incomplete multipart uploads, and any existing object remains undisturbed. The parts of an incomplete multipart upload are only accessible using the multipart API, so, in the only relevant sense, all object creation and overwrite operations -- multipart or not -- are automatically and always 100% atomic. More information on that on the [multipart upload overview](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/mpuoverview.html)
2. You can create a bucket lifecycle policy that cleans up incomplete uploads (**AbortIncompleteMultipartUpload** policy), as detailed in the [lifecycle guidelines](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/mpuoverview.html#mpu-abort-incomplete-mpu-lifecycle-config):

   > Amazon S3 supports a bucket lifecycle rule that you can use to direct
   >   Amazon S3 to abort multipart uploads that don't complete within a
   >   specified number of days after being initiated. When a multipart
   >   upload is not completed within the time frame, it becomes eligible for
   >   an abort operation and Amazon S3 aborts the multipart upload (and
   >   deletes the parts associated with the multipart upload).

   You can attach a rule to only certain prefixes or to the entire bucket, which sounds more appropriate to your use case. You can find more details about bucket lifecycles in the S3 [lifecycle rules docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/intro-lifecycle-rules.html).

Comment: This is almost correct.  An abandoned multipart upload consumes storage space in a holding area, but does not leave an incomplete **object** in the bucket itself. ListObjects, `GET`, etc., cannot see incomplete multipart uploads, and any existing object remains undisturbed.  The parts of an incomplete multipart upload are only accessible using the multipart API, so, in the only relevant sense, **all object creation and overwrite operations -- multipart or not -- are automatically and always 100% atomic.**

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Thanks for the awesome clarification. I think it deserves to be part of the anser (or a new answer). Do you mind me augmenting the answer to include this info?

Comment: This is great information. What puzzles me is that although "all object reaction ... are automatically and always 100% atomic," I'm still seeing remnants of interrupted uploads when I transfer with the `AWSTransferManager`, which is part of AWS's iOS SDK. I cannot see any default or option being set that in that API which would request for this to happen (for instance, to support resumable uploads).

Comment: I'm not an iOS expert, but by looking into the class you mentioned on the AWS iOS SDK (https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios/blob/b79dbbc9b1547684092028792c0a17448265705a/AWSS3/AWSS3TransferManager.m#L226-L231), it looks like that any file above 5MB (https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios/blob/b79dbbc9b1547684092028792c0a17448265705a/AWSS3/AWSS3TransferManager.m#L27) will trigger the multipart upload, thus supporting resumable uploads.

Comment: @Viccari I'm sure it is using multipart for my uploads, since they are large. But again, if "all object creation" is fundamentally atomic, then I would think even a failed multipart upload should not change the state of the bucket in a way that interfered with restarting (rather than resuming) that upload. So I remain puzzled. I will report back what I learn.